# React Native, TypeError: undefined is not an object When it is

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-native, expo

React Native is saying Undefined is not a object when it CLEARLY IS A OBJECt!! I am confused on whats going on.

Look at the following code. Browse down to the `render()` function. See the following... `console.log(cords.coords);`

`console.log(cords.coords);` outputs the following...

```
08:37:22: Object {
08:37:22:   "coords": Object {
08:37:22:     "accuracy": 5,
08:37:22:     "altitude": 0,
08:37:22:     "altitudeAccuracy": -1,
08:37:22:     "heading": -1,
08:37:22:     "latitude": 39.946313,
08:37:22:     "longitude": -82.810829,
08:37:22:     "speed": -1,
08:37:22:   },
08:37:22:   "timestamp": 1522413346644.865,
08:37:22: }
```

One would say that to retrive this data you would have to do the following. `console.log(cords.coords.coords.latitude)` to get the latitude. but it says its undefined. It says its undefined even if I do `console.log(cords.coords.coords)` ? What am I doing wrong ?

Note `console.log(cords.coords);` is where the error is being triggered in the script

## Keep in mind that the following code does work. only when I change `console.log(cords.coords);` to `console.log(cords.coords.coords.latitude);` it breaks

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import {Platform, StyleSheet, Dimensions, Text, View } from 'react-native';
import MapView, { PROVIDER_GOOGLE } from 'react-native-maps';
import { Constants, Location, Permissions } from 'expo';

export default class MapScreen extends Component<Props> {
 constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      markers: [{
        title: 'hello',
        coordinates: {
          latitude: 39.946313,
          longitude: -82.810829
        },
      },
      {
        title: 'hello',
        coordinates: {
          latitude: 39.945838,
          longitude: -82.813018
        },  
      }
     ]
    }
    console.log("Get Geo Synce");
    this._getLocationAsync();
  }

  _getLocationAsync = async () => {
    console.log("load geo sync");
    //Location.setApiKey("AIzaSyBY45685CkDPy5a4ss29IL2ZjIvTvYTMyk");
    let { status } = await Permissions.askAsync(Permissions.LOCATION);
    if (status !== 'granted') {
      this.setState({
        locationResult: 'Permission to access location was denied',
      });
    }
    console.log("Loading Location 1");
    let location = await Expo.Location.getCurrentPositionAsync({ enableHighAccuracy: true });
    console.log("Retrieved Location");
    this.setState({ coords: location });
  };
  
  render() {
    const { params } = this.props.navigation.state;
    let coords = params ? params.coords.coords : null;
    let cords = this.state;
    console.log(cords.coords);
    //let coords = state.locationResult.coords;
    return (
          <View style={{flex: 1}}>
            <MapView
                style={ styles.container }
                initialRegion={{
                    latitude:coords.latitude,
                    longitude:coords.longitude,
                    latitudeDelta:0.0992,
                    longitudeDelta:0.0421,
                }}
            >
              {this.state.markers.map(marker => (
                <MapView.Marker 
                  coordinate={marker.coordinates}
                  title={marker.title}
                />
              ))}
            </MapView>
          </View>
    );
  }
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
      width:'100%',
      height:'100%',
  },
});
```

Comment: Is this the line where the error is: latitude:coords.latitude? Doesn't it refer to coords.latitude and not to cords.coords.latitude?

Comment: `console.log(cords.coords);` is where the error is triggered. ` latitude:coords.latitude` works fine because if you look under the` render()` function. I am pulling that value from `let coords = params ? params.coords.coords : null;` . I created the `cords` variable to eventually replace that.

Comment: Correction If I replace `console.log(cords.coords);` to `console.log(cords.coords.latitude);` the error is triggered

Comment: you mean coords.coords? You have pasted cords.coords. also `let cords = this.state` should always fail since you do a setState({coords}) and not setState({cords})

Comment: It doesnt fail because I am putting the state object in `cords` . therefore to retrieve `coords` i have to do `cords.coords` and it does in fact work. only when I do `cords.coords.coords.latitude` it fails. check out the structure of my object in the post. the terminal data.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's better to make API requests once the component mounts in componentDidMount life cycle method and the problem with your code is, on  initial render this.state.coords is undefined right and once the API request is resolved this.state gets updated with this.setState method and this.state.coords is defined. So to make it work try this,

```
 return this.state.coords instanceof Object ? (
      <View style={{flex: 1}}>
        <MapView
            style={ styles.container }
            initialRegion={{
                latitude:coords.latitude,
                longitude:coords.longitude,
                latitudeDelta:0.0992,
                longitudeDelta:0.0421,
            }}
        >
          {this.state.markers.map(marker => (
            <MapView.Marker 
              coordinate={marker.coordinates}
              title={marker.title}
            />
          ))}
        </MapView>
      </View>
) : <Text>Fetching, Please wait....</Text>;
```

Comment: That is very good to know but thats not where the error is being triggered. I added in my post where the error is being triggered. `console.log(cords.coords);` is where the error is being tirggered. The view at the moment actually works fine because the data in there is being pulled from `let coords = params ? params.coords.coords : null;`

Comment: note if I replace `console.log(cords.coords);` to `console.log(cords.coords.latitude);` the error fires. Right now the above code work fine until I add `console.log(cords.coords.latitude);`

Comment: right now `console.log(cords.coords);` works fine only when I change it to `console.log(cords.coords.latitude);` it breaks. I've update the post. thanks

Comment: correction. only when I do `console.log(cords.coords.coords.latitude);` or `console.log(cords.coords.coords);`  it fails. check out the structure of the object in the post

Comment: on initial load this.state.cords is undefined, render function gets called and because this.state.cords.coords is undefined error may fire.

Comment: This error might occur during initial render() call

Comment: I figured out the issue, but the this.state.coords  instance  of did help me a lot with a work around. thanks. And I am just now realizing the render function is constantly refreshing which makes sense why I should use the instance of object first